# How to get a match when only one letter difference is allowed?

Tags: regex, r, string, data.table

I want to look whether words in my dataset appear in a certain text. When using `grepl` you only get exact matches. With `agrepl` it is possible tot do partial matching. However, I don't get the desired results with it.

Example data:

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                     words = c("weg", "verte", "spiegelend", "spiegeld", "einde", "spiegel", "spiegelende", "weg", "spiegelend", "asfalt", "fata", "morgana")),
                .Names = c("id", "words"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

With:

```
dt <- dt[, .(id, words,
             match1=mapply(grepl, words, 
                           "hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt"),
             match2=mapply(agrepl, words,
                           "hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt",
                           MoreArgs=list(max.distance=1L)))]
```

I get:

```
> dt
    id       words match1 match2
 1:  0         weg   TRUE   TRUE
 2:  0       verte   TRUE   TRUE
 3:  0  spiegelend   TRUE   TRUE
 4:  0    spiegeld  FALSE   TRUE
 5:  0       einde  FALSE  FALSE
 6:  0     spiegel   TRUE   TRUE
 7:  0 spiegelende  FALSE   TRUE
 8:  1         weg   TRUE   TRUE
 9:  1  spiegelend   TRUE   TRUE
10:  1      asfalt  FALSE  FALSE
11:  1        fata  FALSE  FALSE
12:  1     morgana  FALSE  FALSE
```

As you can see, the results from `grepl` and `agrepl` differ on rows 4 and 7. However, I only want a match when there is at maximum one letter difference. The match in row 4 for `match2` should therefore be `FALSE`. Changing parameters like `max.distance` or `costs` doesn't lead to the desired result either. Moreover, both matches on row 6 should be `FALSE` as well.

For example: for the word "*spiegelend*" from the text, the word "*spiegelende*" should give a match (only one letter difference), but the word "*spiegeld*" (two letters difference) and the word "*spiegel*" (three letters difference) should **not** give a match.

The conditions are allowed (but not at the same time):

- one letter more (e.g.: "*spiegelende*" should give a match), or
- one letter less (e.g.: "*spiegelen*" should give a match), or
- one spelling error (e.g.: "*spiehelend*" should give a match)

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jonny5 Actually, `agrepl` is using Levenshtein distance. However, using the parameters specified in `?agrepl` I can't get the desired result.

Comment: @nongkrong How do I do that when I want to match words from a vector against a certain text (as specified in the example)?

Comment: @nongkrong that only takes extra letters into account, when a word from `words` is one letter shorter, I don't get a match (see also the specified conditions in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two ways to solve it, matching the approaches by nongkrong and RHertel:

```
dt <- cbind(dt[,c("id", "words")],
         match1=mapply(grepl, dt$words, 
                       "hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt"),
         match2=mapply(agrepl, dt$words,
                       "hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt",
                       MoreArgs=list(max.distance=1L)),
       match3=mapply(agrepl, paste0("\\b",dt$words,"\\b"),
                       "hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt",
                       MoreArgs=list(max.distance=1L, fixed=F)),
       match4=apply(adist( dt$words,  unlist(strsplit("hoe komt het dat de weg in de verte soms spiegelend lijkt", split=" "))),
                 1, function (x) any(x<=1))
                     )
```

match3 uses the word boundary \\b, while match4 uses an edit distance (adist) of <=1 to single words in a vector

Answer (score 1):

I thought about using `adist()` in this case with the condition `< 2`. But I'm not sure if it yields the expected output. Does this help?

```
idx <- which(adist(dt$words,dt2$words) < 2, arr.ind = T)
dt$match <- (dt$words %in% dt2$words[idx[,2]])
#> dt
#   id       words match
#1   0         weg  TRUE
#2   0       verte  TRUE
#3   0  spiegelend  TRUE
#4   0    spiegeld FALSE
#5   0       einde FALSE
#6   0     spiegel FALSE
#7   0 spiegelende FALSE
#8   1         weg  TRUE
#9   1  spiegelend  TRUE
#10  1      asfalt FALSE
#11  1        fata FALSE
#12  1     morgana FALSE
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                 words = c("weg", "verte", "spiegelend", "spiegeld", "einde", "spiegel", "spiegelende", "weg", "spiegelend", "asfalt", "fata", "morgana")),
            .Names = c("id", "words"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
dt2 <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                   words = c("hoe", "komt", "het", "dat", "de", "weg", "in", "de", "verte", "soms", "spiegelend", "lijkt")),
              .Names = c("id", "words"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```